# Is it possible for a multirow cell to be split across pages when using longtable?

Tags: longtable, multirow

I am using a longtable for a table that spans multiple pages. To my limited understanding, cells cannot be split across pages. However, I was wondering if it's possible for a multirow cell to be split across multiple pages.

In the example below, the second column overflows the page margins instead of continuing on the second page. Is there any way that I can have the cell text continue on the second page apart from manually breaking the second column into multiple multirows?

Thank you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,longtable,multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|p{2in}|p{2in}|}\hline
    \lipsum[1]  & \multirow{25}{\linewidth}{\lipsum[1-2]}\\\cline{1-1}  %1
                &                                       \\\cline{1-1}   %2                              
                &                                       \\\cline{1-1}   %3
                &                                       \\\cline{1-1}   %4
                &                                       \\\cline{1-1}   %5
                &                                       \\\cline{1-1}   %6
                &                                       \\\cline{1-1}   %7
                &                                       \\\cline{1-1}   %8
                &                                       \\\cline{1-1}   %9
                &                                       \\\cline{1-1}   %10
                &                                       \\\cline{1-1}   %11
                &                                       \\\cline{1-1}   %12
                &                                       \\\cline{1-1}   %13
                &                                       \\\cline{1-1}   %14
                &                                       \\\cline{1-1}   %15
                &                                       \\\cline{1-1}   %16
                &                                       \\\cline{1-1}   %16
                &                                       \\\cline{1-1}   %17
                &                                       \\\cline{1-1}   %18
                &                                       \\\cline{1-1}   %19
                &                                       \\\cline{1-1}   %20
                &                                       \\\cline{1-1}   %21
                &                                       \\\cline{1-1}   %22
                &                                       \\\cline{1-1}   %23
                &                                       \\\cline{1-1}   %24
                &                                       \\\hline        %25

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think so unless David does some black magic.

Comment: `multirow` sets the contents into `\vtop`.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113705/text-in-multirow-overlaps-the-next-row#comment250788_113705

Comment: are you sure you want a table here, 99% of the time a two column table with large entries is better set as a list. List entries naturally break over a page.

Comment: I found this solution (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79143/how-to-repeat-cell-content-on-next-page-for-longtable-using-multirow/79152) useful to a problem very similar to this one.