# longtabu with multicolumns & multirows

Tags: multirow, multicolumn, longtabu

I used @Zarko's proposed code. So far, it works except for the multirows, which seem to fall out of the page frame as illustrated in the screenshot. Does anybody have an idea?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow, longtable, tabu}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.8,0.8,0.8}
\usepackage{colortbl}    


\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth { X[1, l] X[1, l] 
                           *{6}{S[table-format=2.3]}
                            }
\toprule
\toprule
& & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{def1}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{def2}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-8}
& & {contrast} & {t} & {p} & {contrast} & {t} & {p} \\ 
\endfirsthead
\toprule
& & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{def1}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{def2}} \\
& & contrast & t & p & contrast & t & p \\
\toprule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{8}{r}{continued on the next page} \\
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

\toprule
\multicolumn{8}{c}{\textbf{group1}} \\
\toprule
\multirow{6}{*}{\textbf{design1}}  
& pos1 & 15.05 & 1.06 & 0.145 & -3.41 & -0.28 & 0.610 \\
& pos2 & 9.20 & 0.65 & 0.258 & -4.02 & -0.32 & 0.627 \\
& pos3 & 32.92 & 2.30 & \cellcolor{gray}0.011 & 4.87 & 0.40 & 0.344 \\
& pos4 & 6.46 & 0.69 & 0.247 & 3.94 & 0.45 & 0.327 \\
& pos5 & 10.99 & 0.87 & 0.191 & 0.41 & 0.03 & 0.486 \\
& pos6 & 36.70 & 2.20 & \cellcolor{gray}0.014 & 30.20 & 1.94 & \cellcolor{gray}0.026 \\
\midrule
\multirow{6}{*}{\textbf{design2}}
& pos1 & 6.51 & 0.87 & 0.192 & -2.79 & -0.41 & 0.661 \\
& pos2 & 1.91 & 0.29 & 0.385 & -3.21 & -0.54 & 0.706 \\
& pos3 & 16.49 & 2.52 & \cellcolor{gray}0.006 & 4.21 & 0.73 & 0.233 \\
& pos4 & 4.42 & 0.96 & 0.168 & 1.15 & 0.28 & 0.391 \\
& pos5 & 0.13 & 0.02 & 0.491 & -0.26 & -0.05 & 0.521 \\
& pos6 & 11.73 & 1.63 & \cellcolor{gray}0.052 & 12.18 & 1.88 & \cellcolor{gray}0.031 \\
\midrule
\multirow{6}{*}{\textbf{design3}}
& pos1 & 17.02 & 1.18 & 0.119 & -5.75 & -0.46 & 0.678 \\
& pos2 & 11.08 & 0.77 & 0.220 & -3.85 & -0.30 & 0.618 \\
& pos3 & 35.82 & 2.41 & \cellcolor{gray}0.008 & 6.00 & 0.48 & 0.316 \\
& pos4 & 9.59 & 0.96 & 0.170 & 1.78 & 0.19 & 0.423 \\
& pos5 & 9.25 & 0.70 & 0.243 & 0.86 & 0.07 & 0.472 \\
& pos6 & 34.91 & 1.99 & \cellcolor{gray}0.024 & 32.28 & 2.04 & \cellcolor{gray}0.021 \\
\toprule
\multicolumn{8}{c}{\textbf{group2}} \\
\toprule
\multirow{6}{*}{\textbf{design1}}
& pos1 & 16.98 & 1.07 & 0.142 & -10.16 & -0.70 & 0.759 \\
& pos2 & 18.47 & 1.10 & 0.136 & 2.77 & 0.18 & 0.429 \\
& pos3 & 15.28 & 1.23 & 0.110 & 16.18 & 1.41 & 0.079 \\
& pos4 & 21.38 & 1.92 & \cellcolor{gray}0.027 & -0.18 & -0.02 & 0.507 \\
& pos5 & 30.56 & 2.54 & \cellcolor{gray}0.006 & 16.49 & 1.50 & 0.067 \\
& pos6 & 29.32 & 3.40 & \cellcolor{gray}0.000 & -7.31 & -0.98 & 0.836 \\
\midrule
\multirow{6}{*}{\textbf{design2}}
& pos1 & 5.45 & 0.71 & 0.239 & -3.97 & -0.56 & 0.712 \\
& pos2 & 9.89 & 1.48 & 0.070 & -0.84 & -0.14 & 0.554 \\
& pos3 & 7.32 & 1.38 & 0.084 & 4.53 & 0.93 & 0.176 \\
& pos4 & 10.15 & 2.04 & \cellcolor{gray}0.021 & -0.86 & -0.19 & 0.575 \\
& pos5 & 11.09 & 2.20 & \cellcolor{gray}0.014 & 3.13 & 0.67 & 0.250 \\
& pos6 & 9.31 & 1.88 & \cellcolor{gray}0.030 & -3.42 & -0.75 & 0.774 \\
\midrule
\multirow{6}{*}{\textbf{design3}}
& pos1 & 16.54 & 1.06 & 0.145 & -7.81 & -0.55 & 0.709 \\
& pos2 & 11.86 & 0.72 & 0.236 & -6.58 & -0.43 & 0.667 \\
& pos3 & 15.75 & 1.29 & 0.099 & 14.89 & 1.32 & 0.093 \\
& pos4 & 25.87 & 2.36 & \cellcolor{gray}0.009 & -1.19 & -0.12 & 0.548 \\
& pos5 & 30.73 & 2.59 & \cellcolor{gray}0.005 & 14.17 & 1.31 & 0.096 \\
& pos6 & 31.61 & 3.66 & \cellcolor{gray}0.000 & -6.28 & -0.85 & 0.802 \\
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: your new images are not produced with your code in question ... regarding to these images I wonder, what actually is your problem? According to image you had solved your problem, however hide solution :(

Answer (score 2):

with using `siunitx` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx} % <-- added
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow, longtable, tabu}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}


%\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth { X[1.5, l] X[1, l] 
                               *{6}{S[table-format=2.3]} % <-- changed
                                }
\toprule
    & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{def1}}   & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{def2}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){3-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-8}
    & & {contrast} & {t} & {p}              & {contrast} & {t} & {p}            \\ 
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
    & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{def1}}   & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{def2}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){3-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-8}
    & & contrast & t & p                    & contrast & t & p \\
\midrule
\endhead
    \bottomrule
\multicolumn{8}{r}{continued on the next page} \\
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
% end of tabu preamble
\multicolumn{8}{c}{\textbf{group 1}} \\
\midrule
\multirow{6}{*}{\textbf{design1}}  
    & pos1  & 15.05 & 1.06 & 0.145 & -3.41 & -0.28 & 0.610 \\
    & pos2  & 9.20  & 0.65 & 0.258 & -4.02 & -0.32 & 0.627 \\
    & pos3  & 32.92 & 2.30 & 0.011 &  4.87 &  0.40 & 0.344 \\
    & pos4  & 6.46  & 0.69 & 0.247 &  3.94 &  0.45 & 0.327 \\
    & pos5  & 10.99 & 0.87 & 0.191 &  0.41 &  0.03 & 0.486 \\
    & pos6  & 36.70 & 2.20 & 0.014 & 30.20 &  1.94 & 0.026 \\
%\midrule
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

I also changed `longtabu` "premble" -- remove duplicated rules. Showed reult is obtained after second run of MWE compilation.

**Edit:**
With my MWE, now completed with whole table I obtain desired and expected result:

[image]

Please, observe differences between proposed MWE below and your code in question! In my MWE I put significant amount of effort needed to clean-up your code. In it are removed all unnecessary `\multicolumns`, redesigned definitions for headers and footers, changes may wrong used rules etc:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow, longtable, tabu}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{showframe}% to show page layout
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth { X[1.5, l] X[1, l]
                               *{6}{S[table-format=2.3]}
                                }
\toprule
    & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{def1}}   & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{def2}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){3-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-8}
    & & {contrast} & {t} & {p}              & {contrast} & {t} & {p}            \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
    & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{def1}}   & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{def2}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){3-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-8}
    & & contrast & t & p                    & contrast & t & p \\
\midrule
\endhead
    \bottomrule
\multicolumn{8}{r}{continued on the next page} \\
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
% end of tabu preamble
\multicolumn{8}{c}{\textbf{group 1}} \\
\midrule
\multirow{6}{*}{\textbf{design1}}
    & pos1  & 15.05 & 1.06 & 0.145 & -3.41 & -0.28 & 0.610 \\
    & pos2  & 9.20  & 0.65 & 0.258 & -4.02 & -0.32 & 0.627 \\
    & pos3  & 32.92 & 2.30 & 0.011 &  4.87 &  0.40 & 0.344 \\
    & pos4  & 6.46  & 0.69 & 0.247 &  3.94 &  0.45 & 0.327 \\
    & pos5  & 10.99 & 0.87 & 0.191 &  0.41 &  0.03 & 0.486 \\
    & pos6  & 36.70 & 2.20 & 0.014 & 30.20 &  1.94 & 0.026 \\
\midrule
\multirow{6}{*}{\textbf{design2}}  
    & pos1  & 6.51  & 0.87 & 0.192 & -2.79 & -0.41 & 0.661 \\
    & pos2  & 1.91  & 0.29 & 0.385 & -3.21 & -0.54 & 0.706 \\
    & pos3  & 16.49 & 2.52 & 0.006 & 4.21  &  0.73 & 0.233 \\
    & pos4  & 4.42  & 0.96 & 0.168 & 1.15  &  0.28 & 0.391 \\
    & pos5  & 0.13  & 0.02 & 0.491 & -0.26 & -0.05 & 0.521 \\
    & pos6  & 11.73 & 1.63 & 0.052 & 12.18 &  1.88 & 0.031 \\
\midrule
\multirow{6}{*}{\textbf{design3}}  
    & pos1  & 17.02 & 1.18 & 0.119 & -5.75 & -0.46 & 0.678 \\
    & pos2  & 11.08 & 0.77 & 0.220 & -3.85 & -0.30 & 0.618 \\
    & pos3  & 35.82 & 2.41 & 0.008 &  6.00 &  0.48 & 0.316 \\
    & pos4  & 9.59  & 0.96 & 0.170 &  1.78 &  0.19 & 0.423 \\
    & pos5  & 9.25  & 0.70 & 0.243 &  0.86 &  0.07 & 0.472 \\
    & pos6  & 34.91 & 1.99 & 0.024 & 32.28 &  2.04 & 0.021 \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{8}{c}{\textbf{group2}} \\
\midrule
\multirow{6}{*}{\textbf{design1}}  
    & pos1  & 16.98 & 1.07 & 0.142 & -10.16 & -0.70 & 0.759 \\
    & pos2  & 18.47 & 1.10 & 0.136 &  2.77  &  0.18 & 0.429 \\
    & pos3  & 15.28 & 1.23 & 0.110 & 16.18  &  1.41 & 0.079 \\
    & pos4  & 21.38 & 1.92 & 0.027 & -0.18  & -0.02 & 0.507 \\
    & pos5  & 30.56 & 2.54 & 0.006 & 16.49  &  1.50 & 0.067 \\
    & pos6  & 29.32 & 3.40 & 0.000 & -7.31  & -0.98 & 0.836 \\
\midrule
\multirow{6}{*}{\textbf{design2}}  
    & pos1  & 5.45  & 0.71 & 0.239 & -3.97 & -0.56 & 0.712 \\
    & pos2  & 9.89  & 1.48 & 0.070 & -0.84 & -0.14 & 0.554 \\
    & pos3  & 7.32  & 1.38 & 0.084 &  4.53 &  0.93 & 0.176 \\
    & pos4  & 10.15 & 2.04 & 0.021 & -0.86 & -0.19 & 0.575 \\
    & pos5  & 11.09 & 2.20 & 0.014 &  3.13 &  0.67 & 0.250 \\
    & pos6  & 9.31  & 1.88 & 0.030 & -3.42 & -0.75 & 0.774 \\
\midrule
\multirow{6}{*}{\textbf{design3}}  
    & pos1  & 16.54 & 1.06 & 0.145 & -7.81 & -0.55 & 0.709 \\
    & pos2  & 11.86 & 0.72 & 0.236 & -6.58 & -0.43 & 0.667 \\
    & pos3  & 15.75 & 1.29 & 0.099 & 14.89 &  1.32 & 0.093 \\
    & pos4  & 25.87 & 2.36 & 0.009 & -1.19 & -0.12 & 0.548 \\
    & pos5  & 30.73 & 2.59 & 0.005 & 14.17 &  1.31 & 0.096 \\
    &¸pos6  & 31.61 & 3.66 & 0.000 & -6.28 & -0.85 & 0.802 \\
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

**Note:**
`longtable` (as well `longtabu`) try to break table between pages on the begin new rows. In case of use `multirow` cells, `longtable` consider them as one row, so it can't be broken between pages (without some package author "black magic", see [question: Is it possible for a multirow cell to be split across pages when using longtable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267811/is-it-possible-for-a-multirow-cell-to-be-split-across-pages-when-using-longtable)).

Since in the my tests of your MWE in question didn't reproduce reported problem I can only concluded,that you have some "black magic" in your computer. An desperate try can be upgrade your LeTeX installation or test your MWE on some other computer or with some other name.

Comment: thanks! I added the result as a pic in my question post. Now the table is too narrow and not aligned. What can I do about this?

Comment: @Mira, do you compile twice? Image seems to show result after first run of the compiler (LaTeX). `longtable` as well `longtabu` had to be compiled twice!

Comment: Thanks for reminding! I updated my question again. Everything works fine except the pagebreak problem (picture in the question post). design2 is outside the table. I really don't get why?

Comment: @Mira, I can't replicate your problem. Please, see edit of my answer. Please test complete MWE, but in this not forget to compile it twice.

Comment: I'm sorry, of course I changed my table according to your solution (with a few less important modifications), but it still doesn't work: design2 will not appear at the next page. I updated my question showing the complete MWE and outcome with page layout.

Comment: @Mira, I test your modification of my proposed solution. And again, I cant' reproduce your problem! Try to delete all files produced by compilation (`.aux`, `.log`, .`pdf`, ...) and try to compile your MWE again. Also it would be nice and very helpful, that in edits of your question you mentioned, that you use my answer and that it still produce problem which try to clear expose. On this ways more people be able to see your problem and eventually help you. I cannot help you further since since I can't reproduce your problem. I'm confident, that my answer solve your original question.

Answer (score 0):

With eg `\lipsum[3]` before the table your problem would be reproducable.

You can avoid page breaks after tabular lines using `\\*`. In the following example page breaks only allowed at the rules.

(Regarding a comment in your [Crosspost on golatex.de](http://golatex.de/longtabu-mit-multicolumns-und-rows-t19064.html): Surround `\cellcolor{gray}` by currly braces to align the numbers in these cells too.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow, longtable, tabu}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.8,0.8,0.8}
\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\lipsum[3]

\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {X[1.5, l] X[1, l] *{6}{S[table-format=2.3]}}
\toprule
& & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{def1}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{def2}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-8}
& & {contrast} & {t} & {p} & {contrast} & {t} & {p} \\ 
\endfirsthead
\toprule
& & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{def1}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{def2}} \\
& & contrast & t & p & contrast & t & p \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\endhead
\multicolumn{8}{r}{continued on the next page} \\
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{8}{c}{\textbf{group1}} \\*
\midrule
\multirow{6}{*}{\textbf{design1}}
& pos1 & 15.05 & 1.06 & 0.145 & -3.41 & -0.28 & 0.610 \\*
& pos2 & 9.20 & 0.65 & 0.258 & -4.02 & -0.32 & 0.627 \\*
& pos3 & 32.92 & 2.30 & {\cellcolor{gray}}0.011 & 4.87 & 0.40 & 0.344 \\*
& pos4 & 6.46 & 0.69 & 0.247 & 3.94 & 0.45 & 0.327 \\*
& pos5 & 10.99 & 0.87 & 0.191 & 0.41 & 0.03 & 0.486 \\*
& pos6 & 36.70 & 2.20 & {\cellcolor{gray}}0.014 & 30.20 & 1.94 & {\cellcolor{gray}}0.026 \\*
\midrule
\multirow{6}{*}{\textbf{design2}}
& pos1 & 6.51 & 0.87 & 0.192 & -2.79 & -0.41 & 0.661 \\*
& pos2 & 1.91 & 0.29 & 0.385 & -3.21 & -0.54 & 0.706 \\*
& pos3 & 16.49 & 2.52 & {\cellcolor{gray}}0.006 & 4.21 & 0.73 & 0.233 \\*
& pos4 & 4.42 & 0.96 & 0.168 & 1.15 & 0.28 & 0.391 \\*
& pos5 & 0.13 & 0.02 & 0.491 & -0.26 & -0.05 & 0.521 \\*
& pos6 & 11.73 & 1.63 & {\cellcolor{gray}}0.052 & 12.18 & 1.88 & {\cellcolor{gray}}0.031 \\*
\midrule
\multirow{6}{*}{\textbf{design3}}
& pos1 & 17.02 & 1.18 & 0.119 & -5.75 & -0.46 & 0.678 \\*
& pos2 & 11.08 & 0.77 & 0.220 & -3.85 & -0.30 & 0.618 \\*% <- remove this * to reproduce the problem
& pos3 & 35.82 & 2.41 & {\cellcolor{gray}}0.008 & 6.00 & 0.48 & 0.316 \\*
& pos4 & 9.59 & 0.96 & 0.170 & 1.78 & 0.19 & 0.423 \\*
& pos5 & 9.25 & 0.70 & 0.243 & 0.86 & 0.07 & 0.472 \\*
& pos6 & 34.91 & 1.99 & {\cellcolor{gray}}0.024 & 32.28 & 2.04 & {\cellcolor{gray}}0.021 \\*
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{8}{c}{\textbf{group2}} \\*
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multirow{6}{*}{\textbf{design1}}
& pos1 & 16.98 & 1.07 & 0.142 & -10.16 & -0.70 & 0.759 \\*
& pos2 & 18.47 & 1.10 & 0.136 & 2.77 & 0.18 & 0.429 \\*
& pos3 & 15.28 & 1.23 & 0.110 & 16.18 & 1.41 & 0.079 \\*
& pos4 & 21.38 & 1.92 & {\cellcolor{gray}}0.027 & -0.18 & -0.02 & 0.507 \\*
& pos5 & 30.56 & 2.54 & {\cellcolor{gray}}0.006 & 16.49 & 1.50 & 0.067 \\*
& pos6 & 29.32 & 3.40 & {\cellcolor{gray}}0.000 & -7.31 & -0.98 & 0.836 \\*
\midrule
\multirow{6}{*}{\textbf{design2}}
& pos1 & 5.45 & 0.71 & 0.239 & -3.97 & -0.56 & 0.712 \\*
& pos2 & 9.89 & 1.48 & 0.070 & -0.84 & -0.14 & 0.554 \\*
& pos3 & 7.32 & 1.38 & 0.084 & 4.53 & 0.93 & 0.176 \\*
& pos4 & 10.15 & 2.04 & {\cellcolor{gray}}0.021 & -0.86 & -0.19 & 0.575 \\*
& pos5 & 11.09 & 2.20 & {\cellcolor{gray}}0.014 & 3.13 & 0.67 & 0.250 \\*
& pos6 & 9.31 & 1.88 & {\cellcolor{gray}}0.030 & -3.42 & -0.75 & 0.774 \\*
\midrule
\multirow{6}{*}{\textbf{design3}}
& pos1 & 16.54 & 1.06 & 0.145 & -7.81 & -0.55 & 0.709 \\*
& pos2 & 11.86 & 0.72 & 0.236 & -6.58 & -0.43 & 0.667 \\*
& pos3 & 15.75 & 1.29 & 0.099 & 14.89 & 1.32 & 0.093 \\*
& pos4 & 25.87 & 2.36 & {\cellcolor{gray}}0.009 & -1.19 & -0.12 & 0.548 \\*
& pos5 & 30.73 & 2.59 & {\cellcolor{gray}}0.005 & 14.17 & 1.31 & 0.096 \\*
& pos6 & 31.61 & 3.66 & {\cellcolor{gray}}0.000 & -6.28 & -0.85 & 0.802 \\*
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that there could be a page break after the rule below of "group" line like in the following picture:

[image]

In that case you have to add a page break manually:

```
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]\pagebreak
\multicolumn{8}{c}{\textbf{group2}} \\*
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
```

Comment: @Vani I have updated my answer. Now the numbers are aligned for the colored cells, too.